# What's special about elliptic cohomology?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, derived-algebraic-geometry, elliptic-cohomology

Apologies for any basic mistakes in this question; I'm a beginner to this theory and don't have anyone at my institution to consult for advice.

What I mean is, if you take an elliptic curve $E$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ say, you should get associated an cohomology theory by taking some deformation of it/putting it in a family and completing. (At least as far as I know, the deformation is necessary, since otherwise LEFT fails at supersingular primes. Is this correct?)

It seems to me that you could pretty much do this with any formal group over $\mathbb{Z}$; just find some deformation so that the heights are all generically $1$, then apply LEFT. (Or is this maybe harder to do than I think? Seems it wouldn't be, though, just from stacky considerations.)

My question is, is there some intrinsic interest in the cohomology theories actually arising from elliptic curves, as opposed to these ones? Or is the reason for the interest entirely because of the geometry of the universal tmf, and its speculative connections to loop groups, the Witten genus, etc.?

Or maybe is the principal interest in the direction of searching for a good equivariant theory which encodes all the elliptic curve's geometry, instead of just its formal Neron model?

Comment: I guess the "intrinsic" interest lies in the fact that these are explicit theories of chromatic level 2. That is, height never goes above 2, and some heights are 2.

Comment: couldn't you write down an arbitrary fgl/Z that does that (using Hazewinkel's/Honda's Dirichlet series formalism for example), put it in a suitable family, and obtain much the same thing? is there any difference besides the elliptic curve one feeling more "god-given"?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but a great thing about elliptic curves is that they come in families, so you can naturally "deform" your cohomology theory. Ultimately this ends up giving you $TMF$ (that has roughly the same relationship with elliptic cohomology that $KO$ has with $KU$)

Comment: Neither am I, but I think @Denis is right - ultimately you need to construct invariants of spaces. Imagine having what you said done for height 1, without any idea of what a vector bundle is. I think it would not be so easy to figure out e. g. why Bott periodicity holds.

Comment: i think the comparison with height 1 kind of illustrates my point - in height 1, you can understand a lot from the 'god-given' nature of usual K-theory because it comes from an explicitly geometric interpretation which has all kinds of consequences. for elliptic cohomology, so long as such an interpretation is lacking, it's hard to justify the specialness of this particular fgl just because it happens to be algebraizable, unless there's some implication thereof i'm not aware of. but maybe the partial work that's been completed on equivariant versions and/or tmf could give a satisfying answer.

Comment: Giving a geometric description of Tmf or TMF is a big open problem a lot of people are interested in. I agree that part of the reason TMF is not used that much in differential geometry is the lack of a geometric interpretation, however if you want an interesting intepretation look no further than the Witten genus (also known as the String orientation of Tmf)

Comment: What do you mean by "LEFT fails at supersingular primes"?  What is "LEFT"?

Comment: landweber exact functor theorem

Comment: I'm confused by your claim that the Landweber exact functor theorem fails at supersingular primes; can you clarify? There are a few "intrinsic" reasons to find tmf and its variants interesting. For one, the Hurewicz image of tmf detects numerous elements in the stable homotopy groups of spheres (I think this fact featured in recent work of Zhouli Xu and Guozhen Wang). Another reason is that, using similar techniques, you can construct an E_oo-ring denoted tmf_1(3) --- which takes effort --- that is the only known E_oo-form of the spectrum BP<2>. I don't know of a geometric perspective on tmf.

Comment: isn't it the case that at supersingular p, v_0=p, v_1=0, v_2=1, which fails to be regular? also i'd be interested in seeing a reference for that last thing you mentioned.

Comment: If you want a Landweber exact thing, then you need to be torsion free. The LEFT still applies, but you're applying it to the *universal deformation ring* of the associated formal group. The thing about BP<2> is proved in Lawson-Naumann; see https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.3897.

Comment: yeah I understand about applying LEFT to the universal deformation ring, or in general pretty much any nontrivial family, as I noted in the question. "If you want a Landweber exact thing, then you need to be torsion free." - I'm a little confused what this means? what exactly needs to be torsion free? LEFT works just fine for height 1 groups without needing to be put in families, for example. and thanks for the link!

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence of your question?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear; I was on my phone. All I meant was the following: in MU-module M must be torsion-free in order to be Landweber-exact MU-module. In particular, if C is an elliptic curve over F_q (supersingular or not), then the associated formal group over F_q will never be Landweber exact, i.e, the map Spec F_q -> M_fg classifying its formal group will never be flat.

Comment: ah, I see what you mean. I guess I didn't specify that I was tacitly talking about elliptic curves over rings of integers, where the breaking point for LEFT happens at height 2.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a partial answer which I find somewhat satisfying: elliptic genera have a natural geometric definition as genera which kill the projective total spaces of even-dimensional complex bundles over compact oriented manifolds, and are closely related to spin geometry and elliptic operators on free loop spaces. This gives a principled way to distinguish elliptic genera from others, coming from geometry. I would still be interested to see if this distinction is possible in purely homotopical terms, or if this is a case where the content really is purely geometrical (and "just happens" to link to the algebraizability of the associated formal group!).